# Best way to track google analytics flow and goals after event

Tags: google-analytics

I have a link on a page that opens a modal window. I want to be able to track a users flow before and (at the very least) after they click on said link. I would also like to see how many people who click on the link go on to complete one of my goals.

What would be the best way to implement and analyze the reports to see this data? I imagine I'd have to either use `_trackEvent` or `_trackPageview`. I like that _trackEvent won't create a false pageView, but am willing to sacrifice for ease of implementation.

My initial thoughts were to use `_trackEvent` Events Flow and/or Visitors Flow. Events Flow is only showing me, for example, 2 people from the US perform the 1st Event then 100% drop off. I'm thinking this is because Events Flow only tracks people form one event to the next and so on, which makes sense to me now but I did not initially understand. Visitors Flow looks to be giving me some of the info I'm looking for (using a custom segment: Event Action matching "click link"), but it only seems to give me the flow a user took up until clicking the link after that there is 100% drop off.

Any help is greatly appreciated.